# regular expression allow value within range

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am facing an issue of matching expected values using regular expression.My expected minimum values is -40500.00 and maximum value is 99,999.99.

Tried 
       ^$|[-][0-9]{0,5}[0-5]{0,3}[0-4]{0,1}|[0-9]{0,5}[.][0-9]{0,2}$";

Comment: what does your regex look like ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a regex or code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but we expect a show of some effort on your part first. Please [edit] your post to be more specific about your requirements (are leading + signs acceptable, are numbers without a decimal point or without a whole number portion acceptable, etc.), include some specific values that should match (as well as some that should *not*), and the regexes you've attempted that didn't work for you. (Of course, the very first question should be *Why a regex for a simple numeric comparison?*)

Comment: It seems to be much easier to convert the value into a floating point numeric (using whatever functionality your language of choice provides) and then just use > and < to make sure the value is within range. It's much less complicated and much easier than jumping through hoops with regexes.

Comment: Yes but I have to do it in regex instead of javascript function

Comment: Can you give your input data?

Comment: any value within the range of -40500 and 99999.99 should be allow

Comment: So it "can be" decimal number or "has to" be decimal numbers ?

Comment: numeric number is fine. "Can be" decimal number

Comment: How about a JS solution without using Regex? Can you explain more about your application?

Comment: The JS solution does not allow me to show the red border box if it is invalid because it is rendered in other library language which I could not edit. That's why I'm looking into regex.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a second structure without the decimals

```
(^$|[-][0-9]{0,5}[0-5]{0,3}[0-4]{0,1}|[0-9]{0,5}[.][0-9]{0,2}$)|(^$|[-][0-9]{0,5}[0-5]{0,3}[0-4]{0,1}|[0-9]{0,5})
```

https://regex101.com/r/bXdE9a/1

Comment: Thank you! I'll test it out.

Comment: What's your input data that doesn't match? Can you do some 'regex101' for it?